# how to pass redshift console output to logger?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I would like to connect to a redshift server using `psycopg2` and execute some SQL statements. I am scheduling this on an airflow server and running via PythonOperator. I would like the redshift server console **output** (STOUT) to be passed back to the `LoggingConnection`, however it only seems to pass the query executed.

The purpose of this is to be able to debug upstream issues and log ETL metadata (in context of the job). Is this possible??

Instantiate a `logger` object and initialize `conn` with the logger. This works, but provides no information besides the query executed.

```
import pandas as pd
import logging
import psycopg2 as pg
import sys
from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection

conn = pg.connect(<.....>)
conn.autocommit = True

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
conn.initialize(logger)

cur.execute("INSERT INTO tableA <select...>")

# Example of what I want to Log:
# [2019-07-15 15:59:51] 2000 rows inserted... in 2 s 318 ms (execution: 2 s 279 ms, fetching: 39 ms)
```

I want the logger to be passed **all** output from the server console, emulating what one would see if they were to run it locally.

Comment: Maybe the cursor's `statusmessage` attribute has what you want? http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.statusmessage

Comment: @alkasm That was my initial thought, but `cursor.statusmessage` only returns the *first* line of executed SQL (not even the whole statement) and not the console output.
My last guess is that this might be possible using asynchronous connections/notifiers/etc